# Use instanceof without knowing the type

Tags: java, instanceof, dynamic-typing

My Java classes represent entities inside a database, and I find it practical to override the `equals` method of my classes to make comparisons by id. So for example in my `Transaction` class I have this piece of code

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Transaction))return false;
    Transaction otherTrans = (Transaction) other;
    if (id == null || otherTrans.id == null) return false;
    return id.equals(otherTrans.id);
}
```

Now it seems a bit ugly to me that every class holds the same piece of code, with only the name of the class changed. I thought about making my classes extend a superclass `MyEntity` where I would write the above method, replacing `instanceof Transaction` with something like `instanceof this.getClass()`, but this doesn't seem to be possible. I also thought about replacing it with `instanceof MyEntity`, but that means two object could be considered equal even if they belonged to different classes, as long as they have the same id.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the dynamic version of the `instanceof` operator, which is `Class`'s `isInstance` method.

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class.

```
if (!(getClass().isInstance(other))) return false;
```

This will not prevent an instance of a subclass from testing `equals` on a superclass object, but a dynamic way of ensuring that it's the exact same class would be to compare the two `Class` objects for equality.

```
if (!(getClass().equals(other.getClass()))) return false;
```

Comment: For this application, the second method which requires the same class seems most appropriate.

Comment: or `if( this.getClass()!=that.getClass() )` ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have an super class with an equals method.

```
// Where ENTITY would be the type of the class to compare, and ID the type of the id
public abstract class ComparableById<ENTITY extends ComparableById, ID> {

    protected abstract Class<?> getEntityClass();
    protected abstract ID getId();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!getEntityClass().isInstance(other)) return false;
        ComparableById o = (ComparableById) other;
        if (getId() == null || o.getId() == null) return false;
        return getId().equals(o.getId());
    }

}
```

And then you can use it in all of your class this way :

```
@Entity
public class TeacherEntity extends ComparablebyId<TeacherEntity, Long> {
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public getEntityClass() {
        return this.getClass();
    }
}
```

Benefits :
 + You avoid code duplication in each classes.
 + All types are suported.
 + No more casts.

Cons :
 - You need to define `getId()` and `getEntityClass()`  method for each of your class.

Comment: Would there be cases where `getEntityClass()` returns something other than `getClass()`? How do you see that being used?

Comment: Here is the weakness, You need to be carefull when you override the function. I can't put the code in the interface, or the calss would be the interface itself, so... But ENTITY generic type restrict types that inherit from ComparablebyId

Comment: You can't override `getClass()`, so if your default `equals()` implementation used `getClass()` rather than `getEntityClass()`, wouldn't it yield the same results?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question, i tried to factorise the `equals` method in the interface. So you no longer need to define `equals method, so... i think i don't understand you question

Comment: Hmm, it looks like a `default` method can't override a method from `Object`. Could you get this to compile?

Answer (score 1):

I like rgetmann's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280674/348975 but it is incomplete.  I think the below code (not in any way tested) completes it.

```
 boolean equals(Object b){
     return getClass().equals(b.getClass())
              && id==getClass().cast(b).id;
 }
```